How to merge 2 equity curves to find their joint performance as a portfolio?
I don't have a stats background so this question could be basic. I have 2 equity curves, produced by 2 trading systems. Each system sets position sizes based on the balance of the account. Also, the sizing ratio on each system is different.
Example:
If the account balance has 1k in it, the 1st system (ratio=1) will trade with 1 lot. When it reaches 2k, we pick 2 lots. The 2nd system (ratio=2) has 1k, it trades with 2 lots. When the account value reaches 1.5k, it trades with 3 lots.
I want to merge these two together to figure out the historical portfolio performance. The problem I have is that the performance of the two systems will affect each other's sizing since both base it off the account balance.
I am not sure if this is the best way to go about it, here is my approach:

Run the backtest on the 2 systems with static sizing
Convert the resulting equity curves to percentage returns
Adjust the returns by some ratio to get the equity curve to look exactly the same as the equity curve produced by the backtest when sizing by account balance using some ratio
Multiply the percentage returns of the 2 systems.

So if system 1 grew by 1%, and system 2 grew by 2%, the result is 1.01*1.02=1.0302 = 3.02%.
Yes this is inaccurate because we would need the two trades to not overlap. Maybe there is a better way?


Convert the returns back to an equity curve, this is the combined portfolio

Is this the most close to accurate method, or is there a better way? How do the pros do this?
